# How to set Gitlab gitlab-ci variables properly

Tags: linux, ssh, continuous-integration, gitlab

I want to set a `gitlab` variable so it can be consumed by the `gitlab-ci.yaml`

The variable I want to set is a `ssh private key` and it is being copied to a server.

**Problem:** - When I set the private key as below, it **changes the structure** of that private key which leads to a incorrect key.

[image]

Private key before: (I will only put a half of the key for security reasons)

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEowIBAAKCAQEAmJwjZmGw7sitfoCb88xpn6bfgoSKVat5j8rvyGgOkX/Eavag
32izNxWbZvQ249nE1rOwpWAmxtN+JyFEo6IlVhfbrwfRGen+RFboARAe5s5/6ETI
c70s68xFmZxHJYJlt+lJoTOz+YnoK4QaIFbFoh/keRTSnIr7gMlDjv7VFH4VBhJ4
Jpp9TtmK5hsmpnESWYameePdFuo9vZFssrqLZXBGISGEOafGuZhT6eh/iG3sNeeK
.
.
.
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Private key after it is being saved to server from the pipeline:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- MIIEowIBAAKCAQEAz26/7zOELE87ColkJBhNWBQcvL7DjhdRCeWmHeeSPZ2PSjZS KP1+a/J0eHuBHvVIOrZB8oyPnfXfpOlga5y2TIvxLTgNNFzbzGScBIYHNQ9sBzAB w3IEiHzkJCYYY3rWuUMlJtLIyWnaIS8CBYQvO/DlcB70V5z9kWuu5VJDvV8esOnH +Pe2pk/08R2Q610UwOm4blJi0UAVd89Cd3/kPuC5xln+wumdqtQ8ZiAKRvZiXUgK 
.
.
.
b4ewuT1RZXkO6WyP/CSdFjEvYi9pxErXYMMY5hFFJCnzQcEQPXqW -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

How can I avoid this disorientation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use base64 encoding before you put text in the variable and then decode variable back into key using base64 as well.

I.e.,

`base64 -w0 your_key_file > key.base64`

Then put contents of `key.base64` into your env variable.

Then in your pipeline do

`echo -n $PRIVATEKEY | base64 -d > key`

Which would put your original key into the *key* file.

*Side note*: be very careful with adding private ssh keys to pipelines. This may pose significant security risk.